# Update an HTML5 attribute through jquery/ajax

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, html

I have this div in my rails view which renders a collection of users:

```
<div id="users" data-current_page="<%=@users.current_page %>">
  <%= render @users %>
</div>
```

and this jquery function (used to load more users on click action)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var current_page = $("#users").attr("data-current_page")
  $("a.next").click(function() {
    var next_page = ++current_page
    $.get("/users.js?page=" + next_page)
    $("#users").attr("data-current_page").replaceWith(next_page) # this doesn't work
    return false;
  });
});
```

In order to increment $("#users").attr("data-current_page"), I tried this:

```
$("#users").attr("data-current_page").replaceWith(next_page)
```

That is to say if data-current_page is set to 1 on a click it will set to 2 etc... but it doesn't work. Is it possible to update this html5 attribute through jquery?

Thanks for any idea!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The proper syntax for changing an [attribute](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) in jQuery is

```
$('#users').attr('data-current_page', next_page);
```

Answer (score 1):

You should check jquery's docs, the syntax you are looking for to set an attribute is

```
$("your_selector").attr("attribute_name",new_value);
```

So in your case, it would be something like:

```
$("#users").attr("data-current_page",++current_page);
```

You should also be careful with your use of ++, as it seems you are incrementing it twice per click!

cheers

Comment: Thanks for your advice I am looking into this

Comment: You're welcome, my recommendation when working with JS, take a browser with a JS console and test your code in it (I really like chrome and it's developer tools).